# What's your workflow for converting a static HTML website to WordPress?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

Case 1 : If you are building the theme from scratch .
Case 2 : If you are using _s or any other starter theme.

I can build WordPress themes.I just wanted to know the right way or best practices to do things.

Comment: Hello @WalidOmonos - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Your question seems to be very broad, considerably vague, and quite possibly opinion-based as well as questionably [on-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (The process of converting a PSD to HTML/CSS is fairly universal - intending the end-product for WordPress does not alter the steps involved). These are all possibly reasons for [closure](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] and file an [edit] to improve your question.

Comment: Hey @bosco , I have made the question more specefic. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Case 1: Building from scratch**

- First you need to create the `Theme Stylesheet` called `style.css` for registering the theme.
- Then create the `index.php` file form your raw `HTML` index file.
- After that break down the `index.php` into `header.php`, `index.php` and `foter.php` to create the primary scaffolding for your theme.
- Then create

  - `functions.php`
  - `archive.php`
  - `page.php`
  - `single.php`
  - `search.php`
  - `comments.php`
  - `front-page.php`
  - `home.php`
  - `date.php`
  - `author.php`
  - `category.php`
  - `tag.php`
  - `attachment.php`
  - `image.php`
  - `404.php`
  - `rtl.css`
- Now create a directory called `assets` and create two more folder called `js` and `css`. Put your themes `CSS` and `JavaScript` files on those directories
- After that enqueue those files in `functions.php` with `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` function.
- And your full scaffolding is done here. Now you're ready to write your loops and related `HTML` to your theme. From here after you follow standard procedure according to WordPress convention to write your theme.

**For Case 2: Using starter theme such as `_s`**

For any starter theme all the scaffolding is already done. So you can start putting you `CSS` and `JavaScript` codes in the `*.css` and `*.js` files given with the starter theme and you can manipulate the loops as well as other codes comes with the starter theme. If we break down the process it would be like-

- Install the starter theme.
- Put your `CSS` codes in the `*.css` file and `*.js` file.
- Start manipulating the theme files for getting your design and functionality.

For both case it would be great if you import the `Theme Unit Test` data provided by WordPress.

Comment: This does not address the question - OP specifically asked for information regarding creating themes from PSD Photoshop documents. Please review the "[answer]" page in our [help] for tips on writing topical answers